# Recipe website with API and JSON using vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, performance, json, api

I'm training **JavaScript** and using **APIs**. So I'm building a **recipe website** that lets you search ingredients and finds you recipes with it.

Here is the link:
https://www.themealdb.com/

I found some code I could help myself with, and that I understood, to build on. I then wanted to have a few available Json informations more to be added to what's printed on the website.

I want to have the list of all ingredients and the measures next to it. Now, **I have found the info** and *have extracted it* **BUT** :

1. the code is **redundant**
2. I know you can make it **more efficient** with a few lines instead of
   all mine
3. I have no idea how to implement the **forEach loop** I think is needed
   there
4. it would be **prettier** if it only printed the ingredients available
   and not every single ingredient slot there is even if it is empty.

Please help me figure this out. I feel like it's **an easy thing that I just can't put my finger on**.

Here is the part of my code I want to optimize :

```
    function mealRecipeModal(meal) {
  console.log(meal);
  meal = meal[0];
  let html = `
        <h2 class = "recipe-title">${meal.strMeal}</h2>
        <p class = "recipe-category">${meal.strCategory}</p>
        <p class = "recipe-category"> ${meal.strArea}</p>
        <div>
            <h3>Ingredients:</h3>
            <p class = "recipe-ingredients">
            ${meal.strIngredient1 + ` ` + meal.strMeasure1} </br>
            ${meal.strIngredient2 + ` ` + meal.strMeasure2}</br>
            ${meal.strIngredient3 + ` ` + meal.strMeasure3}</br>
            ${meal.strIngredient4 + ` ` + meal.strMeasure4}</br>
            ${meal.strIngredient5 + ` ` + meal.strMeasure5}</br>
            ${meal.strIngredient6 + ` ` + meal.strMeasure6}</br>
            ${meal.strIngredient7 + ` ` + meal.strMeasure7}</br>
            ${meal.strIngredient8 + ` ` + meal.strMeasure8}</br>
            ${meal.strIngredient9 + ` ` + meal.strMeasure9}</br>
            ${meal.strIngredient10 + ` ` + meal.strMeasure10}</br>
            ${meal.strIngredient11 + ` ` + meal.strMeasure11}</br>
            ${meal.strIngredient12 + ` ` + meal.strMeasure12}</br>
            ${meal.strIngredient13 + ` ` + meal.strMeasure13}</br>
            ${meal.strIngredient14 + ` ` + meal.strMeasure14}</br>
            ${meal.strIngredient15 + ` ` + meal.strMeasure15}</br>
            ${meal.strIngredient16 + ` ` + meal.strMeasure16}</br>
            ${meal.strIngredient17 + ` ` + meal.strMeasure17}</br>
            ${meal.strIngredient18 + ` ` + meal.strMeasure18}</br>
            ${meal.strIngredient19 + ` ` + meal.strMeasure19}</br>
            ${meal.strIngredient20 + ` ` + meal.strMeasure20}</br>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class = "recipe-instruct">
            <h3>Instructions:</h3>
            <p>${meal.strInstructions}</p>
        </div>
        <div class = "recipe-link">
            <a href="${meal.strSource}">Source here</a>
        </div>
        <div class = "recipe-meal-img">
            <img src = "${meal.strMealThumb}" alt = "">
        </div>
    `;
  mealDetailsContent.innerHTML = html;
  mealDetailsContent.parentElement.classList.add("showRecipe");
}
```

And the JSON info looks like this :

```
dateModified: null
​​
idMeal: "52846"
​​
strArea: "British"
​​
strCategory: "Chicken"
​​
strCreativeCommonsConfirmed: null
​​
strDrinkAlternate: null
​​
strImageSource: null
​​
strIngredient1: "Butter"
​​
strIngredient10: "Potatoes"
​​
strIngredient11: "Butter"
​​
strIngredient12: ""
​​
strIngredient13: ""
​​
strIngredient14: ""
​​
strIngredient15: ""
​​
strIngredient16: ""
​​
strIngredient17: ""
​​
strIngredient18: ""
​​
strIngredient19: ""
​​
strIngredient2: "Onion"
​​
strIngredient20: ""
​​
strIngredient3: "Mushrooms"
​​
strIngredient4: "Plain Flour"
​​
strIngredient5: "Chicken Stock Cube"
​​
strIngredient6: "Nutmeg"
​​
strIngredient7: "Mustard Powder"
​​
strIngredient8: "Chicken"
​​
strIngredient9: "Sweetcorn"
​​
strInstructions: "Heat oven to 200C/180C fan/gas 6. Put the butter in a medium-size saucepan and place over a medium heat. Add the onion and leave to cook for 5 mins, stirring occasionally. Add the mushrooms to the saucepan with the onions.\r\n\r\nOnce the onion and mushrooms are almost cooked, stir in the flour – this will make a thick paste called a roux. If you are using a stock cube, crumble the cube into the roux now and stir well. Put the roux over a low heat and stir continuously for 2 mins – this will cook the flour and stop the sauce from having a floury taste.\r\n\r\nTake the roux off the heat. Slowly add the fresh stock, if using, or pour in 500ml water if you’ve used a stock cube, stirring all the time. Once all the liquid has been added, season with pepper, a pinch of nutmeg and mustard powder. Put the saucepan back onto a medium heat and slowly bring it to the boil, stirring all the time. Once the sauce has thickened, place on a very low heat. Add the cooked chicken and vegetables to the sauce and stir well. Grease a medium-size ovenproof pie dish with a little butter and pour in the chicken and mushroom filling.\r\n\r\nCarefully lay the potatoes on top of the hot-pot filling, overlapping them slightly, almost like a pie top.\r\n\r\nBrush the potatoes with a little melted butter and cook in the oven for about 35 mins. The hot-pot is ready once the potatoes are cooked and golden brown."
​​
strMeal: "Chicken & mushroom Hotpot"
​​
strMealThumb: "https://www.themealdb.com/images/media/meals/uuuspp1511297945.jpg"
​​
strMeasure1: "50g"
​​
strMeasure10: "2 large"
​​
strMeasure11: "1 knob"
​​
strMeasure12: ""
​​
strMeasure13: ""
​​
strMeasure14: ""
​​
strMeasure15: ""
​​
strMeasure16: ""
​​
strMeasure17: ""
​​
strMeasure18: ""
​​
strMeasure19: ""
​​
strMeasure2: "1 chopped"
​​
strMeasure20: ""
​​
strMeasure3: "100g "
​​
strMeasure4: "40g"
​​
strMeasure5: "1"
​​
strMeasure6: "pinch"
​​
strMeasure7: "pinch"
​​
strMeasure8: "250g"
​​
strMeasure9: "2 Handfuls"
​​
strSource: "https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/recipes/chicken-mushroom-hot-pot"
​​
strTags: null
​​
strYoutube: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bXKWu4GojNI"
```

I hope you have all information available to help me.

So to sum it up :
**How do I write the best code to only get the ingredients needed for the recipe and not all the empty strings for some extra ingredients in some other recipes?**

How do I make it both pretty and functional ? - I want to improve my coding but I'd love it if I could do it by learning best practices at the same time !

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ hey ! i guess i want both, i'll do that !
well yes its html but it's in a html.innerHTML = {code up there}.
I can put more of the code if it helps ?

 I kind of want a forEach loop that makes it so i dont have alle the lines up there but only one line and the number at the end of both ${meal.strIngredients} and the other one, changes in a n+1 way... does it make sense ? Im so bad at explaining myself..

Comment: I added the whole javascript function, i can see that i makes more sense, excuse me for the bad formulating.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it's quite a bad idea to code all your HTML in a string like this

```
element.innerHTML = "<div>${meal.strIngredient1}</div>"
```

If you code HTML like this, your editor will think you are typing a string and will not give you warnings for syntax errors. (for example if you forget a closing tag). The proper way to do it is:

```
let div = document.createElement("div")
div.innerText = `${meal.strIngredient8} ${meal.strMeasure8}`
parent.appendChild(div)
```

(Note that you don't need the `+` in between the variables.)

Then, you could optimize your JSON by leaving out the variable names:

```
{ "recipes": [
    { "ingredient" : "basil", "measure" : 3 },
    { "ingredient" : "tyme", "measure" : 4 },
]}
```

This allows you to create a `for` loop that can loop over all the `recipes` like this:

```
for (let meal of recipes) {
    let div = document.createElement("div")
    div.innerText = `${meal.ingredient} ${meal.measure}`
    parent.appendChild(div)
}
```